# Mimicking hard sphere potential in (time integration ) MD for dense system

Tags: potential-energy, research-level, simulations, molecular-dynamics

I'm doing research on Coarsed grained(CG) particles which are densely packed using popular time integration MD program LAMMPS. I want to mimick hard-sphere(HS) which can only be perfectly possible for Event-driven MD. For dilute system, WCA potential is quite good. However, As the system getting denser, CG particles climb up the purely repulsive potential curve and eventually partially overlap. when simulation is done, average of minimum distance between CG particles is about 0.88(diameter is 1; i.e. inter-particle distance is 1 when they contact each other) and WCA potential truncated at 1.1225 is used.

What kind of pair-wise potential will be enough to be accepted as HS potential alternative? or what criteria is used to determine whether a potential that is used is my system is following behavior of HS potential

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [this pseudo-hard sphere potential](http://www.sklogwiki.org/SklogWiki/index.php/Pseudo_hard_sphere_potential):

$$\Phi(r) = 50 \cdot \left(\frac {50}{49}\right)^{50} \epsilon \left[\left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{50}-\left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{49}\right]+\epsilon \ \ \ \text{if} \ \ r<\frac{50}{49} \sigma$$

$$\Phi(r) = 0 \ \ \ \text{if} \ \ r\geq\frac{50}{49} \sigma$$

The idea is basically to take a much steeper version of the usual WAC potential. I never tried it myself, but, quoting from the cited web page:

> Molecular dynamics simulations of this idealised model, when performed at a reduced temperature of $T^{*}=1.5$ reproduces results for the hard sphere model (for example, the Carnahan-Starling equation of state), which is generally only amenable to Monte Carlo simulations, or advanced techniques such as Event-driven molecular dynamics.

Comment: Thanks, I incorporated this potential into my system and got quite good result, though time step was much narrower than what i had expected.